# Adding a Timeline chart/component in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, charts, components

I want to add a simple Timeline component/chart to my ASP.NET application, the component should look like the one in the below URL:
http://www.smartdraw.com/specials/ppc/timelines.htm?id=139669

Any help / recommendations?